# Sending Data to server in JSON format Swift

Tags: json, swift

Server expecting from me  data in JSON format . Like this ;

[image]

. Im trying to send data like this ;

```
func getProductListResponse(typeId : String , type : String) {
    
    let tsoftFilter = [
        
        "key" : type,
        "value" : typeId
        
    
    ] as [String : AnyObject]
    
    print("tsoft filter is \(tsoftFilter)")
    
    
    let serviceParams = [
        
        "store_id" : Config.productListId,
        "page" : currentPage,
        "per_page" : perPage,
        "tsoft_filters" : "\(tsoftFilter)"
        
        
    ] as [String : AnyObject]
```

But it doesn't work where do I making mistake ?

Comment: You have a working POSTMAN sample. POSTMAN can generate Swift code. It's not beautiful Swift code, but it should give you an hint. Did you check it out? https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/#generating-code-snippets-in-postman

Comment: I didn't know that thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the *description* of a dictionary which is not equal to JSON. And according to the screenshot you need even an array of dictionaries.

In this case it's easier to create the JSON literally

```
func getProductListResponse(typeId : String , type : String) {
    
    let tsoftFilter = #"[{"key":"\(type)","value":"\(typeId)"}]"#
    
    let serviceParams : [String : Any] = [
        
        "store_id" : Config.productListId,
        "page" : currentPage,
        "per_page" : perPage,
        "tsoft_filters" : tsoftFilter
        
    ]
    ...
```

By the way a parameter dictionary sent in a network request is never `[String:AnyObject]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 let tsoftFilter = """
 [
    [ "key" : type, "value" : typeId]
 ] 
 """
```

Comment: JSON uses braces to indicate a dictionary, Swift does not.